# How to set or replace values of rows by a previous column value if conditions exist in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I'm trying to solve an issue related to set or replace values in rows by the value of the previous one in certain conditions. The data looks like:

```
Point_ID [1,2,3,1,2,1], Shape_ID [84,85,86,87,88,89]
```

I used mask and shift in conditions if `Point_ID` starts with 1 the `Shape_ID` of the second row should be replaced by the value of the previous row in case the number increases. If not then `Shape_ID` should stay in a row. So I am trying to obtain:

```
Point_ID[1,2,3,1,2,1], Shape_ID[84,84,84,87,87,89]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mask`, `ne`, and `ffill`:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Point_ID':[1,2,3,1,2,1] , 'Shape_ID': [84,85,86,87,88,89]})
print(df)

   Point_ID  Shape_ID
0         1        84
1         2        85
2         3        86
3         1        87
4         2        88
5         1        89

df.assign(Shape_ID=df['Shape_ID'].mask(df['Point_ID'].ne(1)).ffill().astype(int))
```

Output:

```
   Point_ID  Shape_ID
0         1        84
1         2        84
2         3        84
3         1        87
4         2        87
5         1        89
```

Comment: I think he forgot to accept it  , but you have my upvote ~:)

Answer (score 0):

Using `eq,cumsum`

```
df['GroupId']=df.Point_ID.eq(1).cumsum()
df.Shape_ID[df.Point_ID.ne(1)]=np.nan
df.assign(Shape_ID=df.groupby('GroupId')['Shape_ID'].ffill()).drop('GroupId',1)

Out[831]: 
   Point_ID  Shape_ID
0         1      84.0
1         2      84.0
2         3      84.0
3         1      87.0
4         2      87.0
5         1      89.0
```